# What's the most appropriate extension for a simple affiliate program?

Tags: extensions, affiliate

I'm not sure if "best extension" type questions are allowed here, but I'll give it a shot.  The requirements are pretty simple:

- Customers get a link that they can share
- Purchases made through affiliate links get tracked
- Customers get store credit for referrals
- Non-customer affiliates (think: bloggers) can also get a tracking code for referrals
- Payouts will be made manually to bloggers (as opposed to store credit for customers).
- Nothing much needed on the frontend, will pop some basic FB sharing in, etc.
- Licensed for Enterprise Edition

[Affiliates by aheadWorks](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketing/affiliate-programs/magento-affiliate-5709.html) looks pretty good, but I wasn't sure if there were other good options out there.

UPDATE: Affiliates by aheadWorks doesn't appear to support customer credit for referrals, but rather only the "blogger" use case I mentioned above.

UPDATE 2: MageWorld's [Affiliate Pro 3](https://www.mage-world.com/magento-2-affiliate-extension.html) looks pretty good.  I'm not sure if it will allow me to *only* offer store credit to customers, as opposed to also allowing them to actually make withdrawals.

UPDATE 3: The [Referral Bonus and Reward System](http://store.belvg.com/referral-bonus-and-reward-system.html#product_overview) by BelVG seems to have the minimal feature set that I'm looking for actually.

Comment: You can investigate this one: http://www.mage-world.com/affiliate-pro-magento-extension.html also

Comment: Haha that's awesome I literally just found it like 1 minute ago while doing some additional googling.  Looks like it supports store credit which is nice.

Comment: Can you write your updates in a answer and mark it as solution? :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the requirements that I posted, this ended up being the most appropriate extension:
http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/refer-a-friend.html

Customers and affiliates are treated the same way.  This requires some manual work for payouts for affiliates

UPDATE: Some things that I've had to customize myself, which would have been nice to be included in the base module:

- Support for customer groups
- The Stop Processing Rules doesn't work like you might expect it to.  It stops processing on the rule regardless of whether the rule was applied or not
- Replaced the session variables with cookies for longer-lived tracking.
- Replaced the URL format for referrer URLs with something smaller and simpler.
- Implemented click tracking for referrer URL click-through's

UPDATE 2: Ended up rolling my own.  Because of the features mentioned above that I built myself, and also because the database table structure was pretty inconsistent and in a few cases I hit some random cron errors which I didn't get very prompt or useful support responses on.

Comment: Or just brew your own: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/06/creating-an-affiliate-tracking-module-in-magento/

Comment: Nice!  A fitting tutorial :)  Reminds me that I did end up brewing my own :)  Need to udpate the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing my own research and came across your question. I just want to add the the [magento affiliate extension](https://www.jorhna.com)
will meet all your requirements, i.e Customers get a link that they can share
Purchases made through affiliate links get tracked
Customers get store credit for referrals
Non-customer affiliates (think: bloggers) can also get a tracking code for referrals
Payouts will be made manually to bloggers (as opposed to store credit for customers).
Nothing much needed on the frontend, will pop some basic FB sharing in, etc.
Licensed for Enterprise Edition

It covers all of above mentioned and also has much more like multi level marketing that is the most helpful for me so far. They also offer free version that you can try before buying the full one which is also cheap by the way.